# How to set focus to a textbox within content control when clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, contentcontrol

I have a View which contains two views within the view (these are contained within a ContainerControl).
On the other side of the View there's a **Telerik GridView** where the user can select a row. When a row is selected the other side of the View is dynamically changed to another View (and ViewModel). The dynamic view is a simple Grid with a lots of TextBoxes, so nothing special there.

Now when a user wants to enter values to the dynamically loaded View, he has to first click the `ContentControl` and then click again to a `TextBox` he wants to focus. This only happens when the GridView's row is in **Edit Mode**.

I've tried setting the ContentControl's `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"`.

I've also tried settings all other controls with `IsFocusable=False`.

I know there must be a way to do this with WPF events, but I'm not an expert on this area.

I'm settings the dynamic View using Catel's converter like this (don't know it it's relevant):

XAML:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItemViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={catel:ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public MyDataModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return GetValue<MyDataModel>(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set
    {
         SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItemViewModel);
    }
}
public static readonly PropertyData SelectedItemProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedItem", typeof(MyDataModel));

    public ViewModelBase SelectedItemViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                switch (SelectedItem.Type)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return new OneViewModel(SelectedItem);
                    case 2:
                        return new TwoViewModel(SelectedItem);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It cannot be answered without sufficient data as we are unsure on the strategy you have used to load the view dynamically.  If possible, can you make a simple sample application for better understanding?

Comment: Did you tried `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` on your `TextBox`?

Comment: Using the Gopichandar's FocusManager only makes the current textbox always selected and not the one clicked by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing external view (different xaml file) reference and merging the views to one big xaml. For some reason the Telerik's gridiview "stole" the cursor from the referenced view, but when all controls are on the same xaml file everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit weird behavior. The focus should set to the control on mouse click and not the contentcontrol.  I'm not sure what you are doing wrong.  I tried with a sample app and it works as expected.

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ae32d24e-ecc5-4e94-87d8-f3da2ff91ae0/) says that there is no good solution. The only option is to set the content control's `IsTabStop` property to `False` in the control's template and then to add a new property `IsChildTabStop` to which the child parts will be bound. I'm not sure whether it will help you or not.

**Reference:** [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/14c8f3a1-35d7-4058-b69e-685d219d08f5/contentcontrol-istabstop-how-can-i-stop-the-container-getting-tab-focus?forum=silverlightcontrols)

Answer (score 0):

Allright here is an easy solution - not a beautiful one:

This is only the right answer - if you just want to have the `TextBox` have the `Focus` after the View is loaded.

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox self = sender as TextBox;

        if (self != null)
            self.Focus();
    }
```

As I said - this is a work around